# How to query outside model scope in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, scope

In Laravel we know the scope functions as documented here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes.

In my project I want to query all active documents, so I created this scope:

```
class Document extends Model {

//...

public function scopeActive($query)
{
    return $query->whereNotIn('status', ['done', 'expired'])->orWhere(function($query) { 
        $query->whereIn('reviewed', ['pending', 'todo'])->whereNotNull('reviewed');
    });
}
```

Utilizing this scope you can do something like this: `$activeDocuments = Document::active()->get()`. All documents not within this scope are considered archived.

Is it possible to query all documents that not within this scope? E.g. `$notActiveDocuments = Document::notActive()->get();` My query is relatively complex, I do not like to write this query in 'reverse' considering future maintenance.

If not, what is the most solid and maintainable approach to accomplish an 'outside scope' query?

Comment: No, there is no option to reverse scope like that. Also your scope doesn't seem that complex at all.

Comment: The complexity lies in flipping whereNotIn and orWhere. A document is archived when the status is done or expired and when reviewed it is not pending or todo. If maintenance needs to be done, chances are it will cause a problem, because you need to edit the same thing in two queries..

Answer (score 2):

You should move these arrays to model as constants. This way it will work for both scopes

```
class Document extends Model {

    const ACTIVE_SCOPE_EXCLUDED_DOCUMENT_STATUSES = ['done', 'expired'];
    const ACTIVE_SCOPE_INCLUDED_DOCUMENT_REVIEW_STATUSES = ['pending', 'todo'];

    public function scopeActive($query)
    {
        return $query->whereNotIn('status', self::ACTIVE_SCOPE_EXCLUDED_DOCUMENT_STATUSES)
            ->orWhere(function($query) { 
                $query->whereIn('reviewed', self::ACTIVE_SCOPE_INCLUDED_DOCUMENT_REVIEW_STATUSES)
                    ->whereNotNull('reviewed'); // I think this is unnecessary
            });
    }


    // reverse scope should look something like this
    public function scopeNotActive($query)
    {
        return $query->whereIn('status', self::ACTIVE_SCOPE_EXCLUDED_DOCUMENT_STATUSES)
            ->where(function($query) { 
                $query->whereNotIn('reviewed', self::ACTIVE_SCOPE_INCLUDED_DOCUMENT_REVIEW_STATUSES)
                    ->orWhereNull('reviewed'); // I think this is unnecessary
            });
    }
```

Comment: Hi NoOorZ24, I like the idea of constants, I hadn't thought of that yet (+1). This way I don't have to think about the statuses, but still about the complexity, which can cause problems with future adjustments. What do you think is the best approach for that?

Comment: @DirkJan If you want to make it simpler to maintain I'd suggest that you add extra column to your table like `is_active` and set it to `false` when Document is updated in a way to be considered not-active. This way you only need complex logic in one place. Everywhere else you can then use `->where('is_active', true|false)`. Only thing is - you will also have to calculate this for every existing record

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it in the following way, if the query is always the same for both cases:

```
public function scopeActiveOrNotActive($query, $status, $reviewed)
{
    return $query->whereNotIn('status', $status)
        ->orWhere(function($query) use ($reviewed) { 
              $query->whereIn('reviewed', $reviewed)
                 ->whereNotNull('reviewed');
            });
}
```

Knowing that these two variables will always be an array, you just do it this:

```
Document::activeOrNotActive(['foo', 'bar'], ['otherFoo', 'otherBar'])->get();
```

And if i think a bit, I think you can do this:

```
public function scopeActive($query, $status, $reviewed)
{
    return $query->whereNotIn('status', $status)
        ->orWhere(function($query) use ($reviewed) { 
              $query->whereIn('reviewed', $reviewed)
                 ->whereNotNull('reviewed');
            });
}

public function scopeNotActive($query, $status, $reviewed)
{
    return $query->active($status, $reviewed);
}
```

And after just do it:

```
Document::active(['foo', 'bar'], ['foo1', 'bar2'])->get();   

Document::notActive([! 'foo', ! 'bar'], [! 'foo1', ! 'bar2'])->get();
```

But i'm not so sure it works, it just came to my mind.

I hope i helped you.

Comment: `! 'foo'` doesn't work but it is essentially what I need lol